# MSMQ for transfer of files and starting remote process.

Tags: c#, msmq, masstransit

Currently working on a Lab system which has one admin PC and a series of client PCs(Somewhere between 15-24) connected by a c# program and a shared network drive. Currently the system uses a variety of batch files to transfer file and run programs. However the system has a number of issues and I was asked to change the current system. The idea for the new system was to use MSMQ and MassTransit for transferring files. However it seems to me that there is very little documentation of how to achieve this. I am not familiar with MSMQ at all so I would like to know more.

So what I am asking is this:

1. Is MSMQ and MassTransit the right solution?
2. I have a working queue and client but how do I sent a message to say specifically run Chrome on a client PC? Does it work like sending a batchfile or does the client program need to interpret a message?
3. Reading material for MSMQ and MassTransit, seems lacking, is there somewhere where i could read up/see examples of implementation?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

For #2. MSMQ is a transport mechanism for getting data from A to B. You need an application to create the message and another application to process the message. All MSMQ can do is reliably move the message from the outgoing queue on your admin PC to the queues on the client PCs. Everything else is someone else's responsibility.

A component that may be useful is MSMQ Triggers which allows you to configure an action based on the arrival of a particular message. Simple example, a trigger could monitor a queue for messages with a title of "Shutdown" and call "SHUTDOWN.EXE /S" when one arrives. This is a VERY flexible component and often overlooked.